# Parsing a relative url w.r.t absolute URL

Tags: string, url

I have a use case where I have to parse a relative URL like ../x/y/z.txt w.r.t. to a absolute url  like http://example.net/d/e/h.xml.

The end result I was looking at is http://example.com/d/x/y/z.txt.   But in case of relative urls like ../../../../../../../../../../../x/y/z.txt the desired url should be http://example.com/x/y/z.txt. That mean even with excess ../ I should stop navigating back once I hit the host name. I can code this using some standard string manipulations. But wondering if there is any Java classes that can help me in resolving this type of use-cases. I am not sure string manipulations are the most efficient way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using Java.net package. The URI method has `resolve()` method that helps in resolving the relative URL.